# Onclick copy to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

Hey guys actually i'm trying to give my website users a possibility to click on a button and have some predefined text, in my case contact informations, to the clipboard.
These informations are already given in a div tag with the id="footer" and i want to fetch those or predefine them manually in syntax.

At the end of the page is a scissor, this is a after:element, this element ill change to a link or anything other so i can make it work.
Here's a [link to the site](http://goo.gl/IlajQW)

Comment: pretty sure this can't be done with JavaScript cross browser.

Comment: any other cross browser suggestions

Comment: flash is one solution I've come across before - again not fully cross browser, but better than JS for this.

Comment: Automatic copy-to-clipboard is made to be dangerous on some uses, so web browser made it difficult. My advice is to display an `alert("text");` with your text, and tell the user to copy this part, or if you are adventurer, create a modal box with the text to copy !

Comment: Ok, and isn't there a possibility to force the user to decide to copy or not copy to clipboard when he has clicked it, such as a windows prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this jquery plugin:

https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard

This makes it possible to copy text to youre clipboard with a button.

Comment: Thanks this should be the solution, ill report!

won't work in FF automatically, first need to install flash